# How can I create this junction table properly in SQL?

Tags: sql, relational-database

I have a table fahrzeugtyp with primary key typ_id. In that table, there are stored types of vehicles. Another table is ausstattung with primary key ausstattungs_id that stores types of equipment that a user can select for the car. They have an m:n relationship, because every type of vehicle have multiple types of equipment and vice versa. The Junction table is named typ-eq and uses their primary keys as foreign keys. Now I have a table "booking" where I store the user that is doing the booking with user_id as foreign key from the user table. Now my problem is that I need to add which car type with what equipment the user has selected, but I cannot find a way to do this without having multiple values in one row, when I try to use the PK of typ-eq as an FK in the bookings table.

How can i do that so that all the information is stored in one booking row?

Comment: you could start with entering a schema and example data in sqlfiddle.com + showing the statement you tried so far and a result-table showing your wanted result

Comment: I don't understand this completely yet. A user can book a fahrzeugtyp with a set of ausstattungs. Must this be the entire set of ausstattung found in the table typ_eq for the fahrzeugtyp? Or can they book a subset of that? In other words: Does the table typ_eq contain the one allowed combination of ausstattungs per fahrzeugtyp or does it rather show all ausstattungs that are allowed for a fahrzeugtyp  and a user can book a fahrzeugtyp  with any subset of its allowed ausstattungs? Or have I misunderstood all this entirely?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I understood what you said; it is Oracle syntax, but never mind that, it is irrelevant for this discussion. Model is simplified, contains only primary/foreign key columns.

*Trivial* tables first:

```
SQL> create table fahrzeugtyp
  2    (typ_id    number primary key);

Table created.

SQL> create table ausstattung
  2    (ausstattungs_id  number primary key);

Table created.

SQL> create table users
  2    (user_id    number primary key);

Table created.

SQL> create table booking
  2    (booking_id      number primary key,
  3     user_id         number constraint fk_bu references users
  4    );

Table created.
```

Now, table that seems to be bothering you: `typ_eq`. It should combine information from previous tables: `fahrzeugtyp`, `ausstattung` and `booking` (where combination of these three must be unique):

```
SQL> create table typ_eq
  2    (booking_id       number constraint fk_tb references booking,
  3     typ_id           number constraint fk_tf references fahrzeugtyp,
  4     ausstattungs_id  number constraint fk_ta references ausstattung,
  5     --
  6     constraint uk_te unique (booking_id, typ_id, ausstattungs_id)
  7    );

Table created.

SQL>
```

---

You said:

> How can i do that so that all the information is stored in one booking row?

That would be entirely wrong (unless database you use supports *nested tables*, but they are usually *tricky* to use and maintain). If you planned to "expand" that *booking* row to many, many columns which would support many, many vehicles and their equipment (so that it - the table - would look like an Excel spreadsheet), no - don't do that, that's not the way you should take. Because, sooner or later you'll miss yet another column (so you'd have to alter table to add it), and all queries you write would be a nightmare to maintain. Mind you - a new column is added and EVERY query should be fixed!